# Hat Matrix Leverages and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, projection-matrices

If a vector $e_1= (1,0,\dots,0)$ belongs to the subspace $\mathcal{X}$ spanned by the columns of $X$ why must the $H[1,1]$ element of the hat matrix $H=X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$ be $1$?

I feel like this has something to do with the first column of $X$ consisting of all $1$s (intercept column).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $H$ is defined as the projection matrix over the subspace $\mathcal X$. As the vector $e_1=(1,0,...,0)$ belongs to $\mathcal X$, then we will have that $$He_1=e_1$$ but $He_1$ is the first column of $H$, so the element $H[1,1]$ must be $1$.

Comment: Why $He1 = e1$?

Comment: It projects over a subspace that contains $e_1$, so if an element $v$ is already in that subspace, then $Hv=v$

Comment: Why is it then the case that the first column of X does not belong to the subspace $\mathcal{X}$, if $e_{1}$ belongs to $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: @roc11111111 We don't care about what the columns of the $X$ matrix are. Do you know what a projection matrix is? The span of the columns of the matrix $X$ is $\mathcal X$, but you can't say what is the exact order of their columns, furthermore, if you switch some columns of $X$, the matrix $H$ will remain the same.